# How to remove Google virtual mount drive from Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, gnome, google-drive

I tried Gnome 3.18 Google Drive integration feature to access my Google Drive [USE GNOME 3.18 GOOGLE DRIVE INTEGRATION FEATURE IN UNITY, XFCE AND OTHER DESKTOP ENVIRONMENTS [UBUNTU 16.04]](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/use-gnome-318-google-drive-integration.html)

which works fine but I didn't like it as sometimes it hangs my system when I try to open some folders.

Can anyone tell me how to remove this drive ?

[image: img]

Answer (score 16):

Just like you, I tried this feature in Ubuntu 16.04. I thought it was nice but didn't want to use google-drive that way... then I was mildly annoyed by the fact that not even removing my google account and changing the settings on Online Accounts worked. I couldn't find the **Files** switch.

So I found this workaround, I hope this helps somebody.
Locate the file:

```
~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf
```

and edit it. You'll see some blocks of text representing the same settings you could find on the **Online Accounts** menu shown by @nvelosa.

Find the flag `Files enabled=true` under the desired google account and change it to `false`.

In my case I immediately saw nautilus file explorer hiding the shortcut and finding myself annoyed no more.

Comment: This was my same problem and solution. This also works on 17.04. Perfect

Comment: Still works on Ubuntu 18 LTS (I think that's 18.04, right?).  :)

Comment: worked perfect. thx

Comment: Also worked on 20.04

Answer (score 10):

what @ubashu means is the following, Open **Settings** -> **Online Accounts** -> **Google** and disable **Files**.

[image: Like this]

Comment: Please edit my answer to add this to my question.

Comment: @ubashu Your answer did not have enough detail. Is it such a bad thing for someone else to get a few reputation points?

Comment: @nvelosa no it doesn't work.

Comment: Current GUI in Ubuntu 17.04 also features bold red "REMOVE ACCOUNT" which cleans out the config files entirely.

Comment: This probably would be the right way to do it, but in my case, the online accounts displayed no accounts. Editing the config mentioned by @orla4eigner worked.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this feature in Ubuntu 17.04 too but it was not so fair to use. I was annoyed by the fact that in Nautilus was constantly the icon to mount the google remote drive altough I had removed it. The solution reported worked:

rm ~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf

In Ubuntu 17.04 there is not the option:
Settings -> Online Accounts -> Google -> Files.
From there this cannot be disabled.

If you are looking for a better free solution to mount google drive then I advice you google-drive-ocamlfuse since there is no official linux plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings and search for online accounts. Remove google account from there and restart the system. That's it.