# How to remove Google Drive Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, 16.10, google, google-drive

I made my biggest mistake of my life and installed google drive on Ubuntu. Now I cannot uninstall it anymore.
- I uninstalled the google drive package:

```
sudo apt-get remove grive-tools
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
```

- I deleted the all the accounts under Online Accounts
- I unmounted the drive

But it still appears in the file explorer and when I click on it, it automatically revives and sysncs the files back again:

[image]

I want to remove it forever and never ever see it again!

Comment: Try sudo apt-get purge grive-tools. https://askubuntu.com/questions/791700/how-to-remove-google-virtual-mount-drive-from-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: If that's truly the biggest mistake of your life, then you should be a very happy person. Please edit your question to explain all the different ways you installed the software - you must undo each one.

Comment: @arupgsh I tried that several times and it says it cannot find grive-tools

Comment: @user535733 haha! The problem is that I don't remember. I've done that a few weeks ago. I think I've just used: sudo apt-get grive or sudo apt-get grive-tools

Comment: Go to online account settings and remove your Google account.

Comment: @arupgsh 've tried that. I have no more accounts in there. I rebooted and I still have the drive in nautilus